# Multiple jQuery extensions in the same CoffeeScript file

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I want to put more than one jquery extension in the same file.  I have the following in one file:

```
do($ = jQuery) ->
  $.fn.addAlternatingStyles = ->
    $(@).children('tr').not('.exclude').hover(
      -> $(@).addClass('hoverrow')
      -> $(@).removeClass('hoverrow')
    )

do($ = jQuery) ->  
  $.fn.stripe = ->
    $(@).children('tr:even').addClass('evenrow')
    $(@).children('tr:odd').addClass('oddrow')
```

It does not recognise the second extension, i.e. stripe.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That code looks fine to me. It's not a tabs/spaces issue, is it? If you put `alert 'foo'` right before the `$.fn.stripe = ...`, does it get run?

Comment: It works in JS fiddle fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ca3WZ/ What exactly do you mean by "does not recognize"?

Comment: It was a tab problem.  My bad!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use separate `do`.

```
do($ = jQuery) ->
  $.fn.addAlternatingStyles = ->
    $(@).children('tr').not('.exclude').hover(
      -> $(@).addClass('hoverrow')
      -> $(@).removeClass('hoverrow')
    )

  $.fn.stripe = ->
    $(@).children('tr:even').addClass('evenrow')
    $(@).children('tr:odd').addClass('oddrow')
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't explain the issue.